# How can we create arbitrarily long instances of the Euclidean algorithm?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can we create arbitrarily long instances of the Euclidean algorithm? What kind of numbers are useful? What is the relationship between the size of these numbers and the number of steps?

Answer (score 11):

For Fibonacci numbers $F_n$, we have $$\gcd(F_n, F_{n+1}) = 1,$$ and the number of steps in the Euclidean algorithm is $n$ (if you count the last step as $1 = 1+0$).

Comment: and $F(n)$ , $F(n+1)$ are the minimal numbers to produce n steps.

Answer (score 0):

Heropup's solution gives the smallest values for a given length sequence.

Another approach to get a given length of the Euclidean algorithm with a prescribed gcd $=d$ is to set $r_0=0$ and $r_1=d$ (the $r$ values will be the remainders).  Then choose a sequence of (positive integer) quotients of the desired length, say $q_1,\dots q_k$.  Then set $r_{i+1}=q_i\cdot r_i+r_{i-1}$. This will give a Euclidean Algorithm with $k-1$ (nonzero) remainders.

For example, suppose we use $d=3$, and the sequence of quotients $\{2,1,4,1,1\}$.  This gives the sequence of remainders $0, 3, 6, 9, 42, 51, 93$.  So we would take our gcd problem to be $\gcd(93, 51)$, giving us a Euclidean algorithm sequence with $4$ (nonzero) remainders.